# How to add a network drive?

Tags: networking

I was wondering how to add a network drive.  My school has a network drive that shares files between students and teachers. I cannot figure out how to connect it.

I did:
smb:\IP Address

Any help?

---

The server is a Windows and running Windows 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You were almost there with your example ('I did: smb:\IP Address'), but looks like you've got the address wrong, it's got to be in URI format like a web address.

Either go by Clive's example or try these:

- Open up Nautilus/File Manager
- Hit Control + L (to bring up location
  bar)
- Type **smb://(ip_address)/(share)** (though, it'll work without the share name)
- or;
- Click on Browse Network in the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

On Lucid and later versions of Ubuntu: Places, Connect to Server, service type -> Windows share and enter your Windows user name and password. In the Server box you can either put the server's static IP address or its name on the network (ask your school systems administrator for these values if you don't know them).