# How to upload photos from Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I only started using Ubuntu a couple months ago.  I've been able to get pictures from my camera onto the machine.  The system is very different for me and I'm trying to work it out on my own, but I have a homework assignment that requires me to upload JPG files of photos I take and I'm having a problem.

When I click the button on the page to choose a file, I go into the different photo files and nothing shows up, but the screen where files would be turns a very faint orange, just a tint.  I've tried putting the named photos on my desktop, but the upload screen doesn't recognize it at all.

How can I use this software to upload my pictures?

Comment: "upload photos" to ... exactly where? social networking? custom server? please provide details on where are you trying to upload your pictures and if possible a screenshot. Thank you and welcome to AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 3):

First, here are Shotwell's help pages for [**Publishing to the web**](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-upload.html) , and for [**Exporting photos**](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-export.html). You would be **publishing images** (and uploading over the Internet) if your target is a service like Facebook, or Picasa, or Flickr, something like that. You would be **exporting images** if your target is another folder or local drive or a USB key, for example. Since I'm unclear on exactly what you need I'll explain several options.

**Exporting**
If you just need to choose a set of images already in Shotwell, and you can bring them to class on a memory card or burned CD, or even use a [network drive at the school](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36992/how-to-add-a-network-drive), then use the Export function. *Plus, if you are shooting RAW or some other format, and need to convert to JPEG before uploading,* you are going to use the Export function first, even if you are uploading to a web service later. Exporting can both move files and convert image formats, so you may need both functionalities.

- Open Shotwell.
- Select one or more images.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the Export dialogue.
- Choose your export options, file format, size, etc.
- Now just pick a target and your photos are exported, done.

**Publishing**
Shotwell can currently Publish to the following online services: Facebook, Flickr, Picasa Web Albums, Piwigo, Tumblr, Yandex.Fotki, and YouTube. If your target isn't one of these your only option is to Export, explained above.  If you are using one of these services follow the steps below.

- Open Shotwell.
- Select one or more images.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (or click the
  Publish button on the bottom toolbar) to bring up the Publish
  dialogue.
- From there, the steps vary slightly depending on the service. Follow
  the prompts to log-in with the target service, hopefully it is easy
  from that point on.

If you run in to problems just edit your question with which step you are stuck at, so we can edit the answer and make it better.

**Other options**
Also, if you want a really simple option you can just put the pictures for your homework assignment in your [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) folder at which point they are automatically uploaded to your Ubuntu One cloud folder (assuming you have configured the service). [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en) is another good choice, with the added benefit of having a public photo gallery that you could use to show off the photos.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the Online Accounts feature in Ubuntu 12.10.  Shotwell's publishing options won't show most services until the user logs into the services in system settings.

Comment: @eric-yorba can you please edit that in to the answer? I'm using 12.04 still.

Comment: Can someone point me to the place in Lubuntu 12.10, where I can log into these services to get the publishing working from Shotwell ? - right now it opens System Settings window, but there is no obvious way forward...

Comment: Found it. On Lubuntu, the standard dialog doesn't contain "Online Accounts" section. But firing the window from command line helped. it is explain here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202514/how-can-i-manage-empathy-online-accounts-in-lubuntu-12-10