# How can I enable publishing to Facebook using Online Accounts in Lubuntu Shotwell 0.13?

Tags: lubuntu, shotwell

Since upgrade to Lubuntu 12.10, I can't publish photos to Facebook, as the system is now integrated with "Online Accounts", but these can't be configured. There's no relevant entry in the configuration center.

Comment: [Similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/206945/12864), with a reply (but no answer yet) from a Shotwell developer. Try the [help page](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/share-upload.html) and make sure you have authorized Shotwell from Facebook first, then edit your question with any new details.

Answer (score 0):

Close shotwell (all aplication related, like control-center)

Use the shell:

```
sudo leafpad /usr/share/applications/gnome-credentials-panel.desktop
```

Change the line:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

to

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;LXDE;
```

Save and quit. Then, in the shell wirte this:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Add your accounts, open shotwell and export your photos :)

Comment: Good, this helps and Shotwell now opens the window with Online Accounts, but still no way forward... When I click on the account, it makes an authorization roundtrip, but it does not start any kind of publishing from Shotwell... still there must be a piece missing...