# Xubuntu upload photos to Facebook or Picasa via shotwell

Tags: xubuntu, shotwell

I was able to upload easily when I was using unity or gnome shell environment.. But after switching to full xubuntu 12.10.. The options are missing and I can't add them...

Anyone know why?

Comment: Shotwell has its own plugins for uploading to those services. Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/207122/12864) help?

Comment: @TomBrossman Thanks, but that answer is only for gnome-based desktops... for xfce/xubuntu, the only option available is piwigo, and you cant add accounts it via gnome-control-center because it does not seem compatible.

Comment: Sounds like an Xubuntu bug.  Either it needs to include the Ubuntu Online Accounts setup, or it shouldn't include the version of Shotwell that Canonical patched to use their online account system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shotwell 0.13, as Yorba has developed it, does not require Ubuntu Online Accounts.  Ubuntu modified Shotwell to use their UOA system, which is why you're seeing this problem.  We did not realize that this change would make Shotwell not work on Xubuntu.  I don't know if Ubuntu is aware of this either.

I can offer three solutions for you:

1. Use Yorba's PPA to get the latest version of Shotwell for Quantal: https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa
2. Download, build, and install Shotwell from our tar ball: http://yorba.org/shotwell/install.html
3. Install Ubuntu Online Accounts, if it works with Xubuntu (I don't know if it does).

We like to track all bugs with Shotwell, and so this one is ticketed here: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/6069

UPDATE: Ubuntu has acknowledged this is a problem on their end and are working to fix it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/shotwell/+bug/1078642

UPDATE #2: Ubuntu has committed a fix to this problem, I don't know when it will be released.

Comment: Thank you. I like shotwell, so I am gonna try the PPA for now.